# When I deploy to Heroku it gives me a syntax error

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

When I deploy it gives me this syntax error. It works fine locally, even with `heroku local web`. I have tried changing the node engine version in my package.json but it doesn't work.

```
2020-05-26T15:32:27.935809+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app.js:42
2020-05-26T15:32:27.935857+00:00 app[web.1]: );
2020-05-26T15:32:27.935858+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2020-05-26T15:32:27.935858+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-05-26T15:32:27.935864+00:00 app[web.1]: SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
2020-05-26T15:32:27.935869+00:00 app[web.1]: at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
2020-05-26T15:32:27.935870+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
2020-05-26T15:32:27.935870+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
2020-05-26T15:32:27.935875+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
2020-05-26T15:32:27.935875+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
2020-05-26T15:32:27.935875+00:00 app[web.1]: at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
2020-05-26T15:32:27.935876+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
2020-05-26T15:32:27.935876+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
2020-05-26T15:32:27.935876+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
2020-05-26T15:32:27.935876+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/bin/www:7:11)
```

This is the code that gives the error

```js
passport.use(
    new LocalStrategy(function (username, password, done) {
        User.findOne({ username }, function (err, user) {
            if (err) return done(err);
            if (!user) {
                return done(null, false, { message: 'No username found' });
            }
            bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, res) => {
                if (res) {
                    return done(null, user);
                } else {
                    return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect Password' });
                }
            });
        });
    }),
); // <--- this is what it's referring to
```

Comment: Maybe remove the trailing comma in the `passport.use()` argument list, ie `}),` to `})`. Heroku's script parsing is probably using a strict syntax parser

Comment: You have to remove the trailing comma above line 42.

Comment: Thanks guys. It was that comma... and then a few more. Then it started giving me that error from inside the node_modules. Turns out I was using the npm version (6.14.x) in my package.json instead of the node version.